# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project maven-web-application

Tags: sonarqube, maven-plugin

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project maven-web-application.
NFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) @ maven-web-application ---
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.6.0
[INFO] Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.379 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-26T14:03:44Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project maven-web-application: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.PluginFiles: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalConfiguration: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalServerSettings: Unable to load settings: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have build maven project using java 8 and tomcat 8 and configured sonar with jdk 11. but I am getting below error after running command mvn sonar:sonar Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project project-name : Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused
I have tried changing the java version in the POM.xml file `

Comment: I can see two different errors, the one error in the code snippet i.e. `Unable to load component class` and the another error is in the description i.e. `Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused`

It is not clear, which you are trying to fix ?

Comment: Both I'm trying to fix

Comment: For the 1st one i.e. **Unable to load component class**, you need to add the path of the executable sonar-scanner in the Jenkins **Global Tool Configuration**

Comment: For the 2nd one, can you check if your sonarqube is behind any proxy. If yes, then you need to whitelist the connection from Jenkins to sonarqube port 9000